# Cross Platform C++ webserver Library

Tags: c++, embeddedwebserver

I am looking for a cross platform Library in C++ that can run a web server.
Does any one know if tntnet can work on windows computers.
or libmicrohttpd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org) has a HTTP server, among lots of other useful stuff. Runs on Windows, Linux, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Currently tntnet does not support windows. It is possible to port tntnet to windows but nobody has done the work. Sorry.

Comment: I have used tntnet before and enjoyed it, but that was the main reason for this question as there was not any windows support

Answer (score 1):

The boost.asio library documentation includes several example HTTP servers

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

I fond these extremely useful in developing an embedded web server for my own applications.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question directly, but if you have your heart set on one of those, you could always compile them in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found LibHTTP. I have not used it.

https://www.libhttp.org/

https://github.com/lammertb/libhttp